# How to disable currencies except US dollar for my app on Google Play? But I still want to distribute to other countries

Tags: android, google-play, currency, in-app-billing

Does anyone meet similar issue before?

I want to only enable users who use US currency to buy in-app-products. In other words, I don't want to support foreign currencies purchase on Google Play. However, I still want my app be visible and downloadable to users in foreign countries, so they can use free parts of my app.

Thanks for help!

Comment: cant you just look for the `Locale` of the device?

Comment: Why don't you want to take their money? I assume Google automatically converts currency, even if they charge a fee for it.

Comment: for some tax issue, I don't want user to purchase in other currencies except US dollar.